# Successful build. Publish fails with "Class constructor Parser cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

I am seeing the following output when publishing my React App

```
 > react-scripts build
  
  Creating an optimized production build...
  Failed to compile.
  
  Class constructor Parser cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I believe someone may have broken a package I am using because it builds fine locally and rebuilding older builds that were successful in my pipeline now fail with the same error. How can I locate the cause of this issue? There is no other relevant info in the stack trace.

Comment: There's an issue opened on Github already https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9655

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed now. this was an issue with postcss. the fix is released in PostCSS 7.0.34.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, apears to be related with scss package.